# Class that extends jQuery is not an instance of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple class that extends `jQuery`. It doesn't do much except add a couple of extra class-specific methods. The problem, these methods can't exist because the object converts itself into a type `jQuery` and the custom class prototype is gone.

This is what happens:

```
class myClass extends jQuery {
    constructor(){
        super("<div>")
        this.append("<a>")
        // This works as your would expect
    }

    createLink(){
        this.find("a").attr("href", "//google.com")
    }
}

let obj = new myClass();
obj.createLink() // Uncaught TypeError: obj.createLink is not a function
```

what's strange is that outputting the prototype to the console shows that `.createLink` *is* a function:

```
console.log(myClass.prototype) // {constructor: ƒ, createLink: ƒ}
```

What's even more strange, the object doesn't even seem to be an instance of itself:

```
class myClass extends jQuery {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}
console.log(new myClass instanceof myClass) // false
```

But anything else works:

```
class myNewClass extends anyOtherObject {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
}
console.log(new myNewClass instanceof myNewClass) // true
```

The problem only exists when I try to extend `jQuery`. Why is that?

Comment: *"I created a simple class that extends jQuery."* - ...why? Could it be that you're actually trying to write a plugin?

Comment: Um, `new myClacc()` does not match `myClass`

Comment: @Tomalak I am not trying to write a plugin, but good guess. I came across this problem while writing code for a personal project. It is by no means necessary that I extend jQuery for my project. I can easily use something else if I wanted to. I just encountered this issue and wanted to learn more.

Comment: @Diriector_Doc Ah, I see. The sample you gave seemed to push into this direction. Never mind then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `jQuery` is not intended as a constructor. Even if you would call it with `new jQuery()`, you would not get an instance of that "class" back. It simply returns an object explicitly. This is not specific to jQuery. It happens with any function that is not constructor "aware". Simple example:

```js
function A() {
    return { a: 1 }; // Explicit return of object
};

let a = new A;
console.log(a instanceof A); // false

class B extends A {
    myMethod() { }
}

let b = new B;
console.log(b instanceof B); // false
```

To extend jQuery with your own features, define your functions on `jQuery.fn`. See the [documentation on plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/).

Answer (score 6):

Don't write classes that extend jQuery.

jQuery has its own extension point for custom functionality at `$.fn`, and these custom extensions are called [plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

A `createLink` plugin could look like this:

```
$.fn.createLink = function (url) {
    $("<a>", {href: url}).appendTo(this);
};
```

usage:

```
$("div.bla").createLink("https://www.example.com");
```

---

That being said, the global jQuery object is a factory function, not a constructor. When you call `$("something")`, a new jQuery instance will be created internally, and returned.

Extending the factory function will not extend the jQuery instances you receive.